# When I run the main program of my KB im getting compilation error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist

Tags: genexus

Im using

- Genexus X EV3
- Java 11
- Tomcat 9
- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
- Compiler Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\javac.exe
- Make Path: C:\KBs\JavaModel\web\GXJMake.exe
- Interpreter path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe

When I run the model (F5 key), the error output shows:

```
symbol: class XmlType
.\com\javamodel\SdtTileSDT_RESTInterface.java:12: error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

I set environment variable JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11 but didn't work.

Do I need to add some specific .jar file to the Genexus Java Model classpath?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 9 Support was added in GeneXus 15 (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31497,Tomcat+9+support).

Comment: Hello. What happen is I was generating web applications using GX X EV3 U7 with tomcat 9 and Java 11 with no problems before, but my computer was stolen so I restored my Backup KB and now I'm getting this issue. I think something is missing in the classpath. When I restored my backup KB, the classpath sections in Generator properties, comes blank.

Comment: Considering that the properties were "erased" when you restored the backup, perhaps setting "annotations" to "true" could work: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?29399,Use+annotations+for+servlet+definition+property